# pgfmathresult with unexpected result

Tags: etoolbox, pgfmath, textpos

Please have a look at the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,30} {%
   \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\i,8))}%\pgfmathresult
   \begin{textblock*}{1cm}(5cm,5cm)
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {test};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{textblock*}
   \ifnumequal{\pgfmathresult}{0}{\newpage}{}
}
\end{document}
```

When looking at the result there is only a single empty page. Only when 
activating the \pgfmathresult (in the first line in the loop) I get the
desired four pages. But obviously I do not want the resulting digits on 
my pages ...

What do I have to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, `textblock` in absolute mode puts something on the page in the output routine, not in typesetting mode. This means, TeX thinks that nothing has been put on the page, and therefore `\newpage` will do nothing. See section 2.2 of the `textpos` documentation. Solution from that doc: put `\null` before `\newpage`, or anything that produces an invisible output, like `~`.

```
 \ifnumequal{\pgfmathresult}{0}{\null\newpage}{}
```

By the way, now you are putting 8 copies of "test" on top of each other. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the Explanation. No, of course is that not the final result. This is a drastically reduced example from a far more complex file.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The `textblock` environment typesets stuff in a box which does not change to horizontal mode.  In vertical mode `\newpage` has no effect, so you have to add `\leavevmode` before `textblock`.</strike>

The `textblock` environment typesets stuff on shipout which is why `\newpage` sees an empty page and has no effect, so you have to add `\leavevmode` or `\null` somewhere on the page (depending on whether you want the indentation box or not).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,...,30} {%
   \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\i,8))}
   \begin{textblock*}{1cm}(5cm,5cm)
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {test};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{textblock*}
   \ifnumequal{\pgfmathresult}{0}{\leavevmode\newpage}{}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What a simple solution. Many thanks for the quick help!

Comment: Although this solution works, the explanation is wrong. See my answer for a good explanation. `\newpage` certainly does work in vertical mode. It would be very strange if it wouldn't. However, `\leavevmode` has a side effect to insert `\indent`, which causes a empty `\hbox` to be inserted, almost the same as `\null`. The only difference is that the `\insert` box has a width of `\parindent`, while `\null` has width 0.

Comment: @PietvanOostrum Yes, you are right of course.  I revised my answer.  Thank you.